# How to rotate desktop background?

Tags: 12.10, gui

How to rotate desktop background image in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to rotate the background then you should open the image you are using for the background in an image editing application (like [Pinta](http://pinta-project.com/)) and rotate it there. Save the updated image and use it for your background.

Comment: @MickeyTin If this answer solves your problem, you may want to mark it as accepted by clicking the gray check mark to the left of it.